# UPS causes computer to restart when power is restored

Tags: power-supply, reboot, ups

Issue: When UPS switched back from battery to AC (power) the computer restarts. Even if computer is idle (less load)

Scenario steps:

1. UPS is plugged into wall
2. **only** PC is plugged into the UPS
3. Remove UPS into wall -> PC will then use the UPS battery without issues
4. Plugged back the UPS into the wall -> UPS will switch back to AC and it triggers the computer to restart

What might be the possible faulty hardware on this case?

Notes

Cyberpower has a software called power plan personal, which has a *self test* feature that switches power source from AC power to UPS battery and switches back from battery to AC power.

- Only the PC is plugged in the UPS
- UPS is brand new and fully charged
- Cyberpower has a self test software but also fails
- The last logged event in the cyberpower software upon using *self test* feature is

> The UPS has started a battery test process

-> Which I think is because the computer restarted when it switches back from battery to AC power during the test.

**Hardware**

Computer watts usage is around **140~200 watts** (tested and verified via the UPS software and a kill a watt device)

**PC Specs**

**PSU**: Thermaltake smart se 730w(Hold up time of 16msec (minimum) at 80% of full load at 230Vac input.)

motherboard: Aorus Pro b460 AC

processor: i5 10400 2.90ghz~4ghz

ram: 2x 8GB hyper-x fury 2400hz

GPU: MSI GTX 1660 super

x1 gaming keyboard

x1 gaming mouse

x1 webcam

Monitors: x1 AOC 27g2 and x1 BENQ 22" (Note: Monitors are not plugged into UPS)

**UPS**: Cyberpower ut1500e **1500va/900 watts**

- transfer time 4ms as defined in its specs -> https://www.cyberpower.com/ph/en/product/sku/ut1500e#specification

Comment: “Cyberpower has a self test software but also fails” - Sounds like a hardware problem, a real problem in the retail world, is selling old batteries with a new UPS due to the age of the stock. 4 ms is a long time.

Comment: I would suggest to return the UPS.

Comment: @Ramhound, 4ms is still under 16ms of the minimum hold up time of my PSU. I think that should be fine

Comment: It’s obviously not fine if your machine is restarting but I don’t know which self test is failing

Comment: Do you think its because of the transfer time? Manual test and self test(using software) fails.

Comment: @harrymc. Got it. I will let them check this UPS

Answer (score 0):

That has to be a hardware issue with the UPS.
If it is still under warranty have it checked out/replaced by the vendor.
Else get another one or learn to live with it.

It might (and I stress "might") help to place a surge-protector (or power-strip with build-in surge-protector) between UPS and PC.
That might smooth out the spike (I suspect it is a power-spike, or otherwise malformed power-curve, coming from the UPS when it switches from battery to mains power) just enough to let the PSU of the PC handle it better.

Comment: We tried using the UPS with my computer on the shop that it was bought, but the issue did not occur whether its on full load or idle.  This means that the UPS and my computer PSU is working fine. 

I am suspecting the wall sockets has to do with this issue, but I am completely clueless on where to look or start

Comment: Also tried your advice on using a surge protector both between UPS and PC, and also surge protector -> UPS -> PC but unfortunately issue still occurs when it switches from battery to AC power.